# Remove embeded youtube inline css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, youtube

I have embeded a youtube subscribe button on my wordpress but it is coming with padding-top:150%; as inline css from youtube.
How I can remove that padding to put subscribe button at the exact place.

```js
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channelid="UCShv7275jgHM0uvHxZUkG2g" data-layout="" data-count="default"></div>
```

output on this page sidebar.
http://www.jonathanfritzler.org/i-am/

Comment: Does anyone know why that `padding-top` is added?

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery try adding this to the bottom of your html page:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var videoList = document.getElementsByClassName("fluid-width-video-wrapper"); [0].
    videoList.forEach(function(embededVideo) {
      embededVideo.setAttribute("style", "padding-top: 0px;");
    });
  });
</script>
```

If you don't have jQuery, add this to the top of your html page:

```
 <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to override the CSS inside an external iframe. So when you embed a subscribe button or video from YouTube on your website, you won't be able to edit the content inside of that iframe in any way.

However, it is possible to get rid of that 150% padding-top, because it's not within the iframe.

At the time of writing, YouTube's code for an embedded subscription button is similar to this:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>

<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="MyChannel" data-layout="full" data-count="default"></div>
```

This produces the following HTML on the webpage where you place the code (I've left out some of the code for brevity):

```
<div id="___ytsubscribe_0" style="[...]">
    <div class="fluid-width-video-wrapper" style="padding-top: 150%;">
        <iframe [...]></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

That top-padding sits outside of the iframe, so you can target it with CSS. The CSS code below would remove the top padding:

```
/* remove 150% padding top added by youtube subscribe button */
#___ytsubscribe_0 .fluid-width-video-wrapper {
    padding-top: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to overwrite the *padding-top* attribute from class *g-ytsubscribe* in your own *style.css*.

Comment: Try to add !important to the attribute.

Comment: I thin you have not even checked, important is already used in inline css. That's not working.

Comment: Try to change the attribute with JavaScript. That's not a classy solution, but should work.
`var x = document.getElementsByClassName("<your-class>");
x[0].setAttribute("style", "padding-top: <your-value>;");`